# Should I use "is" or "are" in the sentence, "The object of our study is the functions..."?

Tags: grammar

Should I use "is" or "are" in the sentence, "The object of our study is the functions..."?

Since the sentence specifies a singular object ("of our study"), but this object is a collection of things, i.e. it is plural, so should I use "is" or "are" here? "Are" sounds more natural, but I'm not sure.

Comment: *Of our study* does not influence the verb. Are the functions you research the objects of your study? Then the **objects** of our study **are** the functions A, B and C.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use **are**, and make **object of our study** plural to agree with the plural **the functions...**.

> The objects of our study are the functions...

Alternatively, use **is** and use a singular phrase in place of **the functions**

> The object of our study is the set of functions...

Comment: You should explain your use of "subjects" rather than "object" in the sentence.

Comment: @KillingTime No explanation, it was simple error, which I have corrected. Thank you.